# Page navigation on left/right swipe

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to achieve swipe navigation on Windows Phone 7. I would like to navigate from one page to another by swiping left or right. How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to investigate the pivot control -- this is like a tab control where left and right swipes move between pages.  Some of the [labs on Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Learn/Courses/WP7TrainingKit/WP7Silverlight/UsingPivotAndPanoramaControls/Overview) cover them (here, look at Exercise 2 for a walkthrough of creating one).

Answer (score 2):

Look at the GestureService and GestureListener in the [Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/52297)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a horizontal ScrollViewer which contains a horizontal StackPanel. Then put your pages in the StackPanel. Check out http://wp7iphone.codeplex.com for an example of how to emulate the iPhone-style horizontal swipe interface with this approach.

If you want the scrollviewer to "snap" to the nearest page when the swipe stops, it can handle the ManipulationCompleted event and manually adjust its HorizontalOffset appropriately.